# Copying from input to the output text file

Tags: c++, file-io, primes

Hi guys here is my functional code but it does not works properly it should do read numbers from input.txt and count the sum of even,odd numbers in each line then conjunction of prime numbers( which does correctly) and also copy all numbers which are prime to the output.txt

here is my code the problem is : it copies also numbers which are not prime numbers. Thanks a lot !!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ifstream read;
    read.open("input.txt");
    ofstream write;
    write.open("output.txt");
    string line;
    int even, odd, primeXprime;

    if(read.fail())
        cout << "Cant open input.txt" << endl;

    int x, p = 0;

    if(read.is_open())
    {
        while(read, line)
        {
            even = odd = 0;
            primeXprime = 1;
            istringstream sRead(line);

            while(sRead >> x)
            {
                if(x % 2 == 0)
                    even += x;

                if(x % 2 != 0)
                    odd += x;

                for(int i = 2; i <= x; i++)
                {
                    if(x % i == 0)
                        p++;

                    if(p == 2)
                    {
                        primeXprime *= x;
                        write << x << " ";
                        p = 0;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }

            cout << "Sum of even numbers are: " << even << endl;
            cout << "Sum of odd numbers are: " << odd << endl;
            cout << "Sum of prime numbers are: " << primeXprime << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

        read.close();
        write.close();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and observe why numbers that are not primes is printed. Take the number 6 for example and think about how that will flow through your program.

Comment: problem is with your prime detection algorithm

Comment: if (p == 1) instead of if (p == 2)  because you start from i=2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your Primality Testing algorithm , You cannot determine a number is prime or not until you divide it by all the numbers in the range [2,Sqrt(n)]

In line "**if(p == 2)**" you are assuming that it wont be divided by any number later on in the range .

Replace your entire for loop by

```
for(int i = 1; i < x; i++)
{
               if(x % i == 0)
                    p++;
}
if(p < 2)
{
    primeXprime *= x;
    write << x << " ";
}
p = 0;
```